# List controllers are not supported for Task

Tags: tasks, standardsetcontroller, pagination

While doing pagination for task using standardsetcontroller it's throwing error  **List controllers are not supported for Task**

What is the other way to show data on vfpage in pagination format for task record using standardsetcontroller?

```
public ApexPages.StandardSetController setContask {
    get{
        if(setContask == null){
           string queryString = 'SELECT Priority,Subject,Status,Type from Task WHERE Status != \'Completed\'';
            setContask = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(queryString));
            setContask.setPageSize(size);
            noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize();
        }
        return setContask;
    }set;
}

Public List<Task> getTask(){
   return (List<Task>) setContask.getRecords();  
}
```

---

```
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Task}" var="t">
                <apex:column value="{!t.Priority}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!t.Subject}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!t.Status}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!t.Type }"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're going to have to roll your own...You can just implement the same methods as the `StandardSetController` and it should mostly be clear how to do so.

Answer (score -1):

Probably check this link out from salesforce developer forum
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000098QYIAY

Comment: Please cite the relevant content here if the link answers the question.

Comment: @redDevil provide llink have using offset and its limit is only 2000 record but i have 8000 records so my requirement is not fullfilling from this link